# Comparison Statement

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm looking for a statement like this (and for a proof too):

Let $\gamma_1,\gamma_2:\mathbb R\to (M,g)$ two curves (parametrized by arclength) in a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and let $\gamma_1(0)=\gamma_2(0)$ and $\gamma_1'(0)=\gamma_2'(0)$. Now the claim is as follows:

Let $|D_t\gamma_1'(t)|>|D_t\gamma_2'(t)|$ for all $t$ and let $s_1$ respectively $s_2$ be the times, when $\gamma_1$ respectively $\gamma_2$ leave the geodesic ball of radius say $r$ centered at $\gamma_i(0)$ for the first time ($r$ can be small, I'm interested in a local statement).

Then $s_1>s_2$.

The statement seems to be obvious but I can't come up with a proof... Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Is the geodesic ball centered at $\gamma_i(0)$, instead?

Comment: Oh yeah I edit that, it's a typo, I'm sorry.

Comment: Heuristicalyz, if $\gamma_1$ is quicker,  it should leave the ball before $\gamma_2$, am I right? So I would say $s_1<s_2$...

Comment: The curves should be parametrized by their arc length (I forgot to write this). So I think, the one that is more "curved" ($\gamma_1$) should stay longer inside the ball (in terms of curve length). Or am I confused now?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I forgot about this smallness condition. I like your proof (@user29809) very much. In the Euclidian setting, one can use the identity $|\gamma_i(s_i(t))|^2=t^2$, take four derivatives and then find a Taylor expansion of the function $s_i$ around $0$. It turns out, that $s_1$ and $s_2$ agree up to second order and the third order makes the difference (exactly as in your proof), hence the statement is only true for $t$ small enough. I didn't see how to generalize, so thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to answer the question. The goal is to give a Taylor expansion for the function $L$ above from mollyerin's answer: In order to fix notation, the Levi-Civita connection is denoted by $\nabla$. Pick geodesic normal coordinates centered at $p$.
By using the Gauss-Lemma we find

$$\begin{aligned}L(t) &=\int_0^t g\left(\dot\gamma(s),\partial_r(s)\right) \,\mathrm ds\\
& = \int_0^tg\left( (\mathrm d\exp_p)_{\bar \gamma(s)}(\dot{\bar\gamma}(s)),(\mathrm d\exp_p)_{\bar \gamma(s)}\left(\tfrac{\bar\gamma(s)}{\left|\bar \gamma(s)\right|_g}\right)\right)\,\mathrm ds\\
& =  \int_0^tg\left( \dot{\bar\gamma}(s),\tfrac{\bar\gamma(s)}{\left|\bar \gamma(s)\right|_g}\right)\,\mathrm ds\\
& =  \int_0^t\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm ds}\left|\bar \gamma(s)\right|_g\,\mathrm ds= |\bar{\gamma}(t)|_g,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\bar\gamma = \exp_p^{-1}\circ\gamma$. We can expand
$$\bar\gamma(t)=\dot{\bar{\gamma}}(0)t+\frac{\ddot{\bar{\gamma}}(0)}{2!}t^2+\frac{\dddot{\bar{\gamma}}(0)}{3!}t^3+O(t^4)$$
and choose the coordinates such that $\dot{\gamma}(0)=\partial_1$. Since $(\mathrm d\exp_p)_0$ is the identity on $T_pM$, we find $\dot{\bar{\gamma}}(0)=\dot\gamma(0)$.
Since the Christoffel symbols vanish in $p$ (normal coordinates), we obtain $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}(0)=\ddot{\bar\gamma}(0)+\dot{\bar\gamma}^i\Gamma_{1i}^j\partial_j(0)=\ddot{\bar\gamma}(0)$. For the second covariant derivative we compute (using again that the Christoffel symbols vanish in zero)
$$\nabla^2_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}(0)=\dddot{\bar{\gamma}}(0)+\dot{\bar\gamma}^i\partial_1\Gamma_{1i}^j\partial_j(0)=\dddot{\bar{\gamma}}(0)-\frac{1}{3}\left(R^j_{111}+R^j_{111}\right)\partial_j(0)=\dddot{\bar{\gamma}}(0)$$
The equality in the middle uses the identity
$$
\partial_l\Gamma_{jk}^i(0)=-\frac{1}{3}\left(R^i_{jkl}(0)+R^i_{kjl}(0)\right),
$$
that holds in normal coorinates and the last equality uses the symmetries of the curvature tensor.

It follows that
$$
d(p,\gamma(t))^2=|\bar{\gamma}(t)|_g^2 = t^2+\frac{1}{2}\left.g(\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot\gamma,\dot\gamma)\right|_{t=0}t^3+\frac{1}{4}|\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}(0)|^2t^4+\frac{1}{3} \left.g(\dot\gamma,\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}^2\dot{\gamma})\right|_{t=0}t^4+O(t^5)
$$
and since $\gamma$ is parametrized by arc length, $\left.g(\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot\gamma,\dot\gamma)\right|_{t=0}=0$ and $|\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}(0)|^2=-\left.g(\dot\gamma,\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}^2\dot{\gamma})\right|_{t=0}$. This implies
$$
d(p,\gamma(t))^2 = t^2-\frac{1}{12}|\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}(0)|^2t^4+O(t^5)
$$
and applying $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{1}{2}x+O(x^2)$ for $x\to 0$, we obtain
$$
d(p,\gamma(t))=t-\frac{|\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}(0)|^2}{4!}t^3+O(t^4)
$$
which is also in agreement with the examples that have been discussed in the thread.

Answer (score 1):

The proposition you want seems to only be true if $r$ is allowed to depend on the curves $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$.

To be precise, the following statement appears to be false: "Given $p \in M$, there exists some $r > 0$ such that for any $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ satisfying your conditions, $s_1 > s_2$."

As a counterexample, let $M = \mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean metric, $p$ the origin. Fix some $r$.

Let $\gamma_2$ be the curve as follows: For $0 < t < r/2$, $\gamma_2$ is just the unit speed geodesic along the $x$-axis. Then, for $r/2 < t < 3r/4$, $\gamma_2$ makes a half-circle around the point $(r/2, r/4\pi)$; finally, for $t > 3r/4$, $\gamma_2(t)$ is the path $(5r/4 - t, r/2\pi)$.

Now let $\gamma_1$ be the same curve on $0 < t < r/2$, but cause $\gamma_1$ to trace out a (much tighter) full circle for $r/2 < t < 3r/4$ (this time around the point $(r/2, r/8\pi)$), and then continue out along the $x$-axis.

$\gamma_1$ leaves the ball of radius $r$ at time $5r/4$, whereas $\gamma_2$ leaves at some much later time. Now my $\gamma_1$ doesn't satisfy $|D_t \gamma_1'(t)| > |D_t \gamma_2'(t)|$ for $0 < t < r/2$ or for $t > 3r/4$, but it's clear that some small perturbation of $\gamma_1$ will satisfy this condition and still leave the ball earlier. (These curves aren't smooth either but again that can be fixed.)

[**Edit: The rest of this answer appears to be nonsense.** The computation of $L'''_i(0)$ in the proof seems to have several mistakes, and I'm not sure whether they can be fixed; consequently, I'm now agnostic as to whether the proposition below is true.]

On the other hand:

Proposition [**Edit: possibly false**]: Given $p \in M$ and unit speed curves $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ satisfying $\gamma_1(0) = \gamma_2(0) = p$, $\gamma_1'(0) = \gamma_2'(0)$, and $|D_t\gamma_1'(0)| > |D_t\gamma_2'(0)|$, it follows that there is some $R > 0$ such that for all $r < R$, $\gamma_2$ leaves the $r$-ball about $p$ before $\gamma_1$.

Proof [**Edit: flawed**]: Fix normal coordinates around $p$. For $i \in \lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace$ and each $t > 0$ define
$$
L_i(t) = \int_0^t \langle \gamma_i'(s), \partial_r(s) \rangle ds.
$$
As long as $t$ is small enough, $L_i(t)$ is the distance from $p$ to $\gamma_i(t)$. (Here $\partial_r(s)$ is the unit vector in the radial direction at $\gamma_i(s)$.) It's easy to compute
\begin{align}
L_i'(t) &= \langle \gamma_i'(t), \partial_r(t) \rangle \\
L_i''(t) &= \langle D_t \gamma_i'(t), \partial_r(t) \rangle + \langle \gamma_i'(t), D_t \partial_r(t) \rangle.
\end{align}
In particular the second formula implies $L_i''(0) = 0$, so that $L_1$ and $L_2$ agree to second order at $t = 0$. I claim that $L_1'''(0) < L_2'''(0)$, from which the claim follows.

To prove the claim I want to get a nice formula for $L_i'''(0)$. I first remark that $D_t \partial_r(0) = 0$. (This is a computation, but intuitively, $\gamma_i$ is going out from $p$ in the radial direction to first order at $t = 0$, so $\partial_r$ isn't changing to first order.) But then
$$
D_t \langle \gamma_i'(t), D_t \partial_r \rangle \big|_{t=0} = \langle \gamma_i'(t), D_t^2 \partial_r \rangle \big|_{t=0} = \langle \partial_r, D_t^2 \partial_r \rangle \big|_{t = 0} = \langle D_t \partial_r, D_t \partial_r \rangle \big|_{t = 0} = 0. 
$$
(Here I use $D_t \partial_r (0) = 0$ and $\langle D_t \partial_r(t), \partial_r(t) \rangle = 0$ to get rid of unwanted terms.) It follows that
$$
L_i'''(0) = \langle D_t^2 \gamma_i'(0), \partial_r \rangle = \langle D_t^2 \gamma_i'(t), \gamma_i(t) \rangle \big|_{t = 0} = -\langle D_t \gamma_i'(t), D_t \gamma_i'(t) \rangle \big|_{t=0} = - |D_t\gamma_i'(t)|^2
$$
using the fact that $\langle D_t \gamma_i'(t), \gamma_i'(t) \rangle = 0$ since $\gamma_i$ is unit speed. The condition $|D_t \gamma_1'(0) | > |D_t \gamma_2'(0)|$ now implies exactly that $L_1'''(0) < L_2'''(0)$, which is what we wanted.

Comment: There's one more question: Can you explain the function $L$ in some more detail? I don't understand the sentence: "$L_i(t)$ measures the distance from $p$ to the geodesic $\gamma_i$." $\gamma_i$ is not a geodesic around zero, right?

Comment: You mean the geodesic distance from $p$ to $\gamma_i(t)$ right?

Comment: Indeed, I mean to say that $L_i(t)$ is the distance from $p$ to $\gamma_i(t)$. I did not mean to call $\gamma_i$ a geodesic! Will edit that now.

Comment: I have a follow up question since we were discussing a similar problem in another thread: Say I look at the curve $c(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$, then the distance from $c(0)$ to $c(x)$ is given by $\sqrt{2-2\cos x}$ which has the taylor expansion $x-\frac{1}{24}x^3+O(x^5)$ but given your answer I would expect $x-\frac{1}{6}x^3+O(x^4)$. Can you help me out of this confusion?

Comment: @frog I'm not really sure what I was thinking when I wrote this, but it's certainly not true in general that $D_t \partial_r(0) = 0$ (even in a limiting sense), as is shown by your example or the example $\gamma(t) = (t, t^2)$. So the computation for $L'''(0)$ is just incorrect, which means I can't be sure about the proposition anymore. Sorry for the mistake, and thanks for pointing out my confusion!

Comment: Forget my last example; I forgot to parameterize $\gamma$ by arclength. But your example $\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ seems to have $\lim_{s \to 0} (D_t \partial_r)(s) = (-1/2, 0)$ if I've done the computation correctly, so that part of the proof is just wrong, and as you point out my answer gives the wrong value for $L'''(0)$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I get the same value as you (-1/2,0) and my conjecture is that $L'''(0)=-\frac{1}{4}|k_g|^2$ but I was unable to give a rigorous proof. I will try to prove it and maybe write again if I manage to. But thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: I was able to fix this and it turns out that indeed $L'''(0)=-\frac{1}{4}k_g^2$, where $k_g$ denotes the geodesic curvature of $\gamma$ in $p$. If you want I can write out the details but the crucial ingredient is the equation $D_t\partial_r = \frac{1}{2}D_t\dot{\gamma}$ that holds in a limiting sense in $p$ if $\gamma$ is of class $C^3$.

Comment: @frog It's worth writing up as an answer to your own question (and you should then accept it). Provides good documentation in case others have this question in the future.

Comment: I'm sorry its another false alarm. The statement holds for flat metrics so far. For the general case there are subtleties. If I have a full proof I will write it down. But thanks for our help!

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to give a full proof, but i found a reference for the desired result that stands can be found here: http://www.dwc.knaw.nl/DL/publications/PU00018345.pdf Unfortunately I don't understand a few claims and conclusions, so if anybody is able to make sense of it, I'd be grateful to ask questions. The proof is only a few lines (Theorem 5).

Answer (score 0):

This would be true if one of the curves is a geodesic, but otherwise it is not true even in the plane.  Namely, one can send $\gamma_2$ on a circular orbit in such a way that it will never leave the disk, and take for $\gamma_1$ a spiral (or cycloid) that's spinning rapidly (with small coils) so that its second derivative will be bigger than that of $\gamma_2$, but it will gradually travel out of the disk.